# How to evaluate rows in a csv file python

Tags: python, csv

I have this code:

```
import csv

def main():
    file1 = open("filepath", "r")  
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    i = next(reader)
    for row in file1:
        if i[3] < i[4]:
            print("troubling")

        elif i[3] < i[5]:
            print("concerning")
        else:
            print("None")

main()
```

So far, what this has done is split my columns up so I can compare them with each other, however it now is comparing the entire column, rather than within each row, how can i make it do each row instead of comparing two entire columns. Right now column 4's value is the greatest so it prints "troubling" 100 times, I want it to print "troubling" only if a certain row's 4th column is greater than that same rows 3rd column. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why aren't you using `for row in reader:`?

Answer (score 3):

It is simpler to iterate over the reader object. Try the following:

```
import csv
def main():
    file1=open("filepath","r")
    reader=csv.reader(file1)
    for row in reader:
        if row[3]<row[4]:
            print ("troubling")
        #... and so on
```

each row in reader is a list, and so you access each column using the appropriate index.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error is due to you using the variable 'i' inside the loop instead of row. The value of 'i' is not changing within the loop and hence you get the same result every time.

```
for row in file1:
    if row[3] < row[4]:
        print("troubling")
    elif row[3] < row[5]:
        print("concerning")
    else:
        print("None")
```

I believe this should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed my problem. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you please upvote and select my answer as accepted. Cheers!

Comment: This will not work as expected - the `for row in file1` will loop line-wise over the contents of the file. In the consequence `row[3]` will access the line as an array of characters - no CSV parsing is happening here.

Comment: I think it should work. I have previously worked with csv package and thats how I always did row wise reading. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader